# Programmatically verification of a smart contract on a Nextjs component

Tags: javascript, hardhat, nodejs, verify, nextjs

I have come across a situation in my project ( Hardhat, Nextjs, TailwindCSS ) where I need to verify my smart contracts right after their deployment. Clearly, we have a mother smart contract that generates them and keep track of everything.

I know how the verification process is done by the hardhat console, but I don't want to do this part manually! In fact, I need every new smart contract to be verified after my command that I initiated from a Nextjs component.

Does anyone know how to run the "verify" command of the Hardhat console within my javascript file ( Nextjs component )?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [Etherscan API](https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically) to programmatically verify a contract. Alternatively, here is a list of similar guides for other popular chains:

- [PolygonScan API](https://docs.polygonscan.com/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically)
- [BscScan API](https://docs.bscscan.com/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically)

Note that not all the popular blockchains right now have an endpoint for programmatically verifying a smart contract.

In your case, make a POST request to the Etherscan endpoint right after deployment sending all the required parameters in order to verify the targeted smart contract.